# bootstrap datetimepicker not working in DIV class

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put in a bootstrap datetimepicker in my customized table. But it just won't work. i understood that you can't placed a script in th, so i placed it in td, but it's still not working.

Simple and working datepicker.

```
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td><!-- mktime(hour, minute, second, month, day, year) -->
<input type="text" name="call_date" value="<?php echo $adjdate;?>" id="datepicker" class="input-small">
</td>
</tr>
```

---

When i tried to implement bootstrap date time picker, it just won't work. I think i've misplaced something in the code below here.

```
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

---

Additional info:
i forgot to mention that i've added in

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

---

But if i placed code outside instead of putting inside td, it will work

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I just need advice regarding this, and thanks for showing me those examples, it helps a lot, thank you

Comment: Should it be really in a `div` and not in an `input`?

Comment: i just tried out the some of the codes in http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and tried to apply the codes from there. For my situation, i need the datetimepicker to work in my table. For the example in bootstrap datetimepicker, they put it in div class, you can have a look through the look i attached here. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `Jquery` ,`moment.js` before `datetimepicker`.

```js
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

install the package
Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('.datepicker').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' });
    jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   <!-- Bootstrap v3.3.5 -->
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Core.js"></script>
```

Comment: yep but u have to include the package and file then try it works

Comment: I see, okay then

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal-header__training-start">Start at
                <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-start" class="datetimepicker-start" data-function="training-start">
                <div class="datetimepicker-icon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="top:3px;"></span>
                </div>
```

```
$("#datetimepicker-start").datetimepicker(
{
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
});
```

I think the selector must be the input to start datetimepicker.

You have to include 2 files to project: bootstrap-datetimepicker.js &  bootstrap-datetimepicker.css