# datePicker does not show up when used inside div row

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-datepicker

I am writing the below template in single file component **ui.vue**.

It displays datePicker that works fine if I do not put it inside 
`<div class="rows"><div class="col-sm-3">` but if I put it inside of table row made of div like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cols">
            <div class="input-group col-sm-3 date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar col-sm-3"></span></span></div></div></div>
```

then datePicker stops working or stop showing at all, I get no error in console. What might be going on ?

I saw this is duplicate of [bootstrap datetimepicker not working in DIV class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366190/bootstrap-datetimepicker-not-working-in-div-class)

but according to answer I am already loading the jQuery and moment.js before datetimepicker.

See below how I am loading:

```
var $ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
import moment from 'moment'
import eonosdandatetimepicker from 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
import Vue from 'vue';
```

Comment: Possible for you to provide a link with to some sort of demo to work with? Create one demo but add both methods of trying to display the datepicker 'Comment one out' That would make things much easier to work with and find the reason for your problem. Maybe a [**PasteBin.**](https://pastebin.com/) Thank you.

Comment: html tag is case-insensitive, you should use `date-picker` instead of `datePicker`